gradle errors : application crashed
hello everyone i had developped an application with xml and java
the application crashed for this reason
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iseeu, PID: 32375
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iseeu/com.example.iseeu.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.iseeu. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.iseeu. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(FirebaseStorage.java:106)
        at com.example.iseeu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 

and when i open to the the emplacement of error on the MainActivity.java show this line
 FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
       

the probleme is with FirebaseStorage or with getInstance()?
how to fix this type of errors
i stay with this same error 4weeks
thank you for helping me <3

The problem has nothing to do with Gradle. You are only using Gradle to execute the application. The title is misleading. Please edit it.

Where are you calling FirebaseApp.initializeApp?

FirebaseApp.initializeApp after the methde oncreate   :    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);
MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {

First call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) in onCreate method of activity. then other things. It will solve your error.
Code
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity2.this);
    }
}


it doesnt help me bro

please the full code

i will send the full code give me your contact

share your main activity full code here... simply modify your question
